# Consumir WebService con PHP y NuSoap

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Alguien me puede ayudar en lo siguiente tengo un web service, la cual tengo 2 parámetros id y estatus, el problemita que tengo es como hacer que no salga Array(EnviarID_ESTResult) del resultado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esa información te sale porque estás visualizando con print_r. Si quieres sólo visualizar el valor, prueba poniendo echo $respuesta['EnviarID_ESTResult'];

Comment: muchas gracias.